# Pass view as data to js in symfony

Tags: javascript, symfony

I am tryng to implement a search function in my index page using java script. I hav got a form to enter the name and when apply serach, the index page will get updated and load the new index page with the search results

Here is the form in my index page

```
<div id="content">
  <form id="myForm" action="{{path('index_search')}}" method="POST" >
    Write your name here: 
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name_id" value="" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
  </form>
 </div>
<div id="output">#current index</div>
```

Here is the action exexcuted

```
public function searchAction()
       {
       $request = $this->get('request');
       $name=$request->request->get('formName');

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entities = $em->getRepository('SystemVmsBundle:VisitorsDetails')->findOneByfirstname($name);

            $view = $this->render('SystemVmsBundle:VisitorsDetails:index.html.twig',array(
                'entities' => $entities,
            ));
            $return=array("responseCode"=>200,  "view"=>$view);

            $return=json_encode($return);//jscon encode the array
       return new Response($return,200,array('Content-Type'=>'application/json'));
}
```

Here is the js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

   //listen for the form beeing submitted
   $("#myForm").submit(function(){
      //get the url for the form
      var url=$("#myForm").attr("action");

       $.post(url,{
           formName:$("#name_id").val(),
           other:"attributes"
       },function(data){
           //the response is in the data variable

            if(data.responseCode==200 ){
                $('#output').html(data.view);

                $('#output').css("color","red");
            }
           else{

              alert("An unexpeded error occured.");


           }
       });
      return false;
   });


   });
```

However my js is working,but can not pass data as view to the js.How to pass the view 'index.html.twig' to the js?

When inspects with firebug,i got like

```
{"responseCode":200,"view":{"headers":{}}}
```

Any ideas?Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the dataType on your $.post function, like this:

```
$.post(url, {formName: $("#name_id").val(), other: "attributes"}, 
  function(data) {
    if(data.responseCode == 200){
      $('#output')
        .html(data.view)
        .css("color","red");
    } else {
      alert("An unexpeded error occured.");
    }
  }, 'json');
```

But If you only need the html, not other data inside the json, you should change the logic, render a normal template and use dataType 'html'. goes like this:

```
// ...Controller.php
$view = $this->render('SystemVmsBundle:VisitorsDetails:index.html.twig',array(
    'entities' => $entities,
));
return new Response($view);

// index.html.twig
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {formName: $("#name_id").val(), other:"attributes"},
  success: function (data) {
    $('#output').html(data).css("color","red");
  }
});
```